# Adding class libraries as project reference in dotnet core causes to access its dependencies as well

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Consider the following project structure (as attached):

Solution:

- FirstClassLibray

  - FirstClass.cs
- SecondClassLibrary (References FirstClassLibrary Project)

  - SecondClass.cs
- MainWebProject (References SecondClassLibrary Project)

So, in the main project i should only access classes in SecondClassLibrary but what actually happening is that i have full access to all classes in FirstClassLibrary and SecondClassLibrary.

Why this happens? and how to prevent accessing not referenced class libraries?

[Project Structure and the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6AuH.jpg)

Comment: _"i have full access to all classes in FirstClassLibrary"_ - how do you determine that? Also, even if you'd only reference the `Second` project, as soon as you use `FirstClass`, the runtime is going to require the `Second` library because you use `Second.SecondClass` in your `First.FirstClass` constructor. So why don't you tell us what actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This is known as "transitive dependencies", which is just how it works with newer versions. You can do something with `PrivateAssets`, but some people say it's really not worth it.

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes the PrivateAssets property is solved the issue.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in .NET Core Dependencies are Transitive by default :

Read More : [.NET Core Transitive Dependencies and how to block them](https://curia.me/net-core-transitive-references-and-how-to-block-them/)

Add this block to Project.csproj that you want to hide the assets.

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <PackageReference>
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <ProjectReference>
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Comment: it is not related to access modifiers as the same behavior is not happening when using .net framework. the problem is how the main project who is only referencing the second class library can access classes from a non-referenced assemblies?!

Comment: @SayedKhalaf; Sorry for the miss understanding your issue. I just edit the answer. check it out. Thanks @Kirk for the reminder.

Comment: Note that private assets make the library not expose those dependant packages as dependencies. This will also mean that if the library **uses** these packages and the application does not add the dependencies in other means, then this will cause runtime errors.